# I set field value w/ javascript, onchange not triggered. Alternative solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onupdate

I have read some solutions to this, none of which are hassle free, so I thought maybe some modern solution now exist to remedy this. It should anyways, since the problem has been around for a while. Something in the more recent jQuery updates perhaaps?

I set my form field like this:

```
parent.window.document.getElementById(parent.window.imageInputField).value = '{{ path }}'+image;
```

and I have an onchange event like this that I would like to fire upon my field update as of above.

```
$('#data_1').change(function(){
img = "url(" + $('#data_1').val() + ")"
$('#slide_bg').css("backgroundImage", img );
});
```

---

UPDATE

so this code works fine:

```
alert( $('#'+parent.window.imageInputField, window.parent.document).val() );
```

while this doesn't do anything, no error or nothing

```
$('#'+parent.window.imageInputField, window.parent.document).change();
```

The change event is defined here

```
$('#data_1').change(function(){
alert('change event called');
img = "url(" + $('#data_1').val() + ")"
$('#slide_bg').css("backgroundImage", img );
});
```

and this works perfect:

```
<input type='button' value='Uppdatera förhandsgr.' onclick="$('#data_1').change()" />
```

All I want is to trigger what this button does, but by code... anyone see where I went wrong?

Comment: I don't understand, you are looking for an onChangeProperty event?

Comment: Yes, that fires when I javascript-programattically change the contents of an input field (the onchange event only fires when the user puts the cursor in the field, updates the contents and blurs from the field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to trigger the change handler with your code. Updating a value with script will not trigger `change` event

```
parent.window.document.getElementById(parent.window.imageInputField).value = '{{ path }}'+image;
$('#data_1').change()
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Is there a good way to call that from withing this IFRAME (as is obvious from parent.window.document etc. the form field populated, thus it's change event, is within the parent window...
I tried both window.opener.$("#data_1").change() and $( "#data_1", window.opener.document ) without success...

Comment: is jQuery available in iframe?

Comment: try `$(parent.window.document).find('#data_1').change()`

Comment: not working =( I am sure I have stumbled across a way of doing this like a year ago, but now I can't seem to find it =(

Comment: I see now however that I can access the element because I can print out that form fields value, it's obviously just a matter of fireing the change function, that's where my prob is...

Comment: I accepted your answer, I see the principle works in example code, though I can't get it to work in my implementation, the error must be somewhere else, thanks for solving that step for me though!